My routing doesn't work, only blank pages are being shown
I've made 2 different paths, 1 where I can get an overview of all artists and 1 where I can add new artists. The code in this app.routes.ts is as follows:
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AllArtistsComponent } from './artists/all-artists/all-artists.component';
import { AddArtistComponent } from './artists/add-artist/add-artist.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
  path: '',
  component: AllArtistsComponent,
},
{
  path: 'add-artist',
  component: AddArtistComponent,
}

];

I tried applying some other solutions on Stackoverflow like adding differen imports to my app.component.ts like Routerlink, Routermodule, RouterLinkActive, RouterOutlet and CommonModule, but didn't solve the problem for me. The App.component.html consists out of just a navbar and a <router-outlet></router-outlet>
i've created my own app-root.module.ts since it wasn't created by my CLI and added the following code:
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  exports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ]
})
export class AppRootModule { }


Please post the code wherein you import your RouterModule for your AppModule

@nll_ptr I've just updated my question and added the code of my app-root.module to it.

The exported variable routes is not used. Please call the RouterModule.forRoot() method instead the normal install. This allows you to configure the routes

You need RouterModule.forRoot(routes) as your import

I've just changed the import as advised, but the page is still empty, and I get no errors in the console of my browser or IDE.

Are you using "standalone components"? See that, in this case you need use provideRouter, see official docs
